# How to convert pandas dataframe columsn from float64 to object dataype

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Need to convert pandas dataframe columsn from float64 to object datatype with mentioning the column name.

**Input Data**

```
customer_number|email_type|email|phone_type|phone
123|ABC|Primary|abc.def@dd.edu|Mobile|+12345678
```

**Data type :**

```
Customer_number       int64
first_name           object
email_type           object
email                object
phone_type           object
phone               float64
```

**Expected Output Data type**

```
Data type :
Customer_number       int64
first_name           object
email_type           object
email                object
phone_type           object
phone                object
```

**Code**

```
df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv",sep="|")
df['phone'] = df['phone'].astype(str).str.replace('\.0', '')
```

**I don't want to mentioned columns name in code. It should be work for all the columns which has float64 datatype.**

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv",sep="|", dtype={'phone':str})`

Comment: Can you please tell me something without mentioning the column name